# short type variable automatically extended to integer type?

Tags: c

I wanna print the value of b[FFFC] like below,

```
short var = 0xFFFC;
printf("%d\n", b[var]);
```

But it actually print the value of b[FFFF FFFC].

Why does it happen ?

My computer is operated by Windows XP in 32-bit architecture.

Comment: what is your compiler ?perhaps Your compiler does not support `short`

Comment: cite me a single C compiler in the world that doesn't support the `short` type...

Comment: @Pakosz cool down...
@SjB short is guaranteed C Standard universally... like in: it's knife armed cows raining, but you still have your short=16bits on C language. That and long=32bit, etc, etc, etc... int, is machine dependent, though.

Comment: @jpinto3912: short and long are not of a guaranteed fixed size either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`short` is a signed type. It's 16 bits on your implementation. 0xFFFC represents the integer constant 65,532, but when converted to a 16 bit signed value, this is resulting in -4.

So, your line `short var = 0xFFFC;` sets var to -4 (on your implementation).

0xFFFFFFFC is a 32 bit representation of -4. All that's happening is that your value is being converted from one type to a larger type, in order to use it as an array index. It retains its value, which is -4.

If you actually want to access the 65,533rd element of your array, then you should either:

- use a larger type for `var`. `int` will suffice on 32 bit Windows, but in general `size_t` is an unsigned type which is guaranteed big enough for non-negative array indexes.
- use an `unsigned short`, which *just* gives you enough room for this example, but will go wrong if you want to get another 4 steps forward.

Comment: I had just almost finished typing almost word for word the same except to say that the compiler probably issued a warning to say that 0xFFFC wasn't a valid short value - warnings are there for a reason - do not ignore them.

Comment: He could also use the `size_t` type, which is _the type given by the standard to store array indexes_! Seriously, people, how come no one uses `size_t` when they're supposed to?

Comment: size_t wasn't always around, so many people have old knowledge, or are learning from old books/tutorials/etc.  Even on some embedded compilers, you don't get size_t.

Comment: Chris is quite right, I'll edit. The reason I didn't think to suggest `size_t` is probably just that I've been bullied out of it by C++, where the "most correct" type for an index is usually `typename std::something_long<WINDED>::size_type` or something. So you lose the will to live and just use `int` for constants known to be "small". But this is C.

Answer (score 1):

In current compilers we can't use `short` (16 bit) if write `short` use 32 bit . 
for example i compile same code with gcc4 in Ubuntu Linux 32 bit :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    short var = 0xFFFC;
    printf("%x\n", var);
    printf("%d\n", var);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and output is :

```
fffffffc
-4
```

you can see cast short to 32bit normal and use sign extension in 2's complement

Comment: you're conclusion from observation is wrong... short var is 16bits. Do a var++ loop, see where it overflows.

Comment: @ jpinto3912 what is your conclusion ? printf can't show 16bit data ? if this how to `char c = 'c'; printf("%x",c);`

Comment: don't want to down-vote. But: (I) current compilers *can* use short". (II) the question was not about printf, it was about indexing an array with datatype 'short' (... and I got this wrong too at first). (III) printf can show 16bit data. But then the type specifier 'h' is needed, e.g. with '%hx'.

Answer (score 1):

use **%hx** or %hd instead to indicate that you have a short variable, e.g:

```
  printf("short hex: %hx\n", var);     /* tell printf that var is short and print out as hex */
```

**EDIT**: Uups, I got the question wrong. It was not about printf() as I thought. So this answer might be a little bit OT.

**New**: Because you are using **var** as an index to an array you should declare it as **unsigned short** (instead of short):

```
unsigned short var = 0xFFFC;
printf("%d\n", b[var]);
```

The 'short var' could be interpreted as a negative number.

To be more precise:

You are "underflowing" into the negative value range: Values in the range from 0x0000 upto 0x7FFF will be OK. But values from 0x8000 upto 0xFFFF will be negative.

Here are some examples of *var* used as an index to array b[]:

```
short var=0x0000;; // leads to b[0]        => OK
short var=0x0001;  // leads to b[1]        => OK
short var=0x7FFF;  // leads to b[32767]    => OK
short var=0x8000;  // leads to b[-32768]   => Wrong
short var=0xFFFC;  // leads to b[-4]       => Wrong

short var=32767;   // leads to the same as b[0x7FFF]   => OK
short var=32768;   // compile warning or error => overflow into 32bit range
```

Comment: what the reason for b[FFFC] convert to b[FFFFFFFC]?

Comment: it does not convert to b[0xFFFFFFFC]. To be picky: it does not convert at all. It is interpreted/evaluated as b[-4]

Answer (score 1):

As a refresher on the C's data types available, have a look [here](http://www.space.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html).
There is a rule, and that concerns the usage of C, some datatypes are promoted to their integral type, for instance

```
char ch = '2';
int j = ch + 1;
```

Now look at the RHS (Right Hand Side) of the expression and notice that the `ch` will automatically get promoted as an **int** in order to produce the desired results on the LHS (LHS) of the expression. What would the value of `j` be? The ASCII code for '2' is 50 decimal or 0x32 hexadecimal, add 1 on to it and the value of `j` would be 51 decimal or 0x33 hexadecimal.

It is important to understand that rule and that explains why a data type would be 'promoted' to another data type.

What is the `b`? That is an array I presume that has 655532 elements correct?

Anyway, using a format specifier `%d` is for of type int, the value got promoted to an int, firstly, and secondly the array subscript is of type `int`, hence the usage of the `short var` got promoted and since the data size of an int is 4 bytes, it got promoted and hence you are seeing the rest of the value 0xFFFF 0xFFFC.

This is where the usage of *casting* comes in, to tell the compiler to **cast** a data type to another which explains in conjunction to Gregory Pakosz's answer above.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: +1 At long last, an answer that mentions type promotion. After the C question this afternoon where everyone (in question and answers) was using "declared" to mean "defined", I was beginning to despair.

Comment: @pascal: no you are not right about the term "declaration". When you write  "short var = 0xFFFC" it is a declaration and a definition and an initialization all at once. In C you have to use "extern short var" to express "declaration only".

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba: +1 for your comment above! Please check the C FAQ specifically section 1 which covers declarations, definitions in questions 1.11, 1.25 for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You were expecting to store JUST a 16bit variable in a 32bit-aligned memory... you see, each memory address holds a **whole** 32bit word (hardware).

The extra FFFF comes from the fact that short is a **signed** value, and when assigned to **int** (at the printf call), it got signed-extended. When extending two-complements from 16 to 32bit, the extension is done by replicating the last N bit to all other M-N on it's left. Of course, you did not intend that.

So, in this case, you're interested in absolute array positions, so you should declare your indexer as **unsigned**.

Answer (score 0):

In the subject of your question you have already guessed what is happening here: yes, a value of type `short` is "automatically extended" to a value of type `int`. This process is called *integral promotion*. That's how it always works in C language: every time you use an integral value smaller than `int` that value is always implicitly promoted to a value of type `int` (unsigned values can be promoted to `unsigned int`). The value itself does not change, of course, only the type of the value is changed. In your above example the 16-bit `short` value represented by pattern `0xFFFC` is the same as 32-bit `int` value represented by pattern `0xFFFFFFFC`, which is `-4` in decimals. This, BTW, makes the rest of your question sound rather strange: promotion or not, your code is trying to access `b[-4]`. The promotion to `int` doesn't change anything.